# Android 10 - unable to take PersistableUriPermission on a file that I created in getExternalFilesDir()

Tags: uri, file-permissions, android-10.0

Using the below code snippet, we created a file in Android 10, in a sub-folder under getExternalFilesDir(). However, immediately after creation, if we try to take persistableUriPermission, it throws an exception "No such permission exists....".
We need that check to know if that file will be available for read later in a common utility, else we have to make a copy. Please let us know what we might be doing wrong and how to fix this. Appreciate your help.

```
ParcelFileDescriptor filePFD =
    cxt.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(Uri.parse(pathFileToSend), "r");
FileDescriptor fd = filePFD.getFileDescriptor();
FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(fd);

File fileBaseFolder = new File(Utils.GetRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), Utils.DESTINATION);
if (!fileBaseFolder.exists())
fileBaseFolder.mkdirs();

if (fileBaseFolder.exists()) {
File copyFile = new File(fileBaseFolder.getAbsolutePath(), nameOfFile);

FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(copyFile);
byte data[] = new byte[4096];
long total = 0;
int count;
while ((count = fIn.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    fOut.write(data, 0, count);
}

fOut.close();

Uri copiedFileUri =
    FileProvider.getUriForFile(cxt,
        cxt.getString(R.string.file_provider_authority),
        copyFile);
if (null != copiedFileUri)
{
    try {

    /*At this line, an exception is thrown - No persistable permissions exist.. */
    cxt.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(copiedFileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`takePersistableUriPermission()` is for `Uri` values that you get from the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`). It will not work for `FileProvider`. And, you do not need permissions to work with `getExternalFilesDir()` on Android 4.4 and higher.